# DataForm WebPart not showing column 'Append Changes to Existing text'

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a column type 'multiple lines of text' and selected ‘Append Changes to Existing text'. On the default display/edit forms the data shows up as expected.

I then needed to alter the form so fire up SPD and create new forms, don’t make any changes to the form but make it default. However when the new form is rendered the data from this particular field is missing. What can be wrong and whats the resolution ?

UPDATE:
When a Display newform is created in SPD a 'Data View Webpart' is added automatically. This is the line I think thats causing the problem :

```
 <xsl:value-of select="@Body" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

The Body is the original column name which I changed to 'Milestones later.

Cant find anything on the net that seems to work, any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I tried this before but didnt work, on 2nd attempt it worked..must have missed something 1st time round ..
http://unitedsupplyco.sharepointsite.net/publicfacing/bensblog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=35d5d43d%2D59b2%2D45bb%2D8fbb%2D3e856b0b12a0&ID=41

Answer (score 1):

You can try replacing this line:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@Body" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

with

```
<SharePoint:AppendOnlyHistory FieldName="Body" runat="server" ControlMode="Display" ItemId="{@ID}"/>
```

ControlMode can be changed to Add or Edit as per requirements